# Python C API segmentation fault when launching python soft twice

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I'm trying to run a python code from a C code twice but I get a segfault the second time.

Here is my c code:

```
//prgm.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Python.h"

int main(void) {
    int i;
    Py_Initialize();

    /* add . to the path */
    PyObject* sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
    PyObject* path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
    PyList_Insert(path, 0, PyUnicode_FromString("."));

    /* import desired function */
    PyObject* pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("main");
    PyObject* pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "main");

    /* call it */
    PyObject* pArgs = Py_BuildValue("(s)", "137912500");
    PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
    i=Py_FinalizeEx();
    fprintf(stderr,"End of python software");
    Py_Initialize();
    i=Py_IsInitialized();

    
    /* add . to the path */
    sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
    path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
    PyList_Insert(path, 0, PyUnicode_FromString("."));
    
    /* import desired function */
    pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("main");
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "main");

    /* call it */
    pArgs = Py_BuildValue("(s)", "137912500");
    PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
    Py_Finalize();
    fprintf(stderr,"End of python software");
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my python code:

```
def main(freq):
    print("test python")
```

With the gdb I see that `i=Py IsInitialized()` returns true.

I also see that the segfault occurs at pModule line on the second call of python code.
There seems to be a memory leak:

```
Thread 1 "scheduling" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:
```

Could you explain to me what I'm doing wrong please?
I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and I use Python 3.8.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: As a general rule, there's plenty of common C modules (e.g. Numpy) that *don't* support being imported multiple times after Python has been closed an re-initialized. Your example looks simple enough that it should work, but you won't find it reliable for more complex modules.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for these explanations, I will try to handle opening the python soft in different processes.